# Paypal nothin happend

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9

We had set up an new them from template monster to update to 1.9

the site is running well but at the check out with paypal nothin happend.

If you click on the paypal button it will go direct to the final step and nothin happend. No error, no redirection nothing.

for better understanding 
[www.ungezogen-angezogen.ch/test](http://www.ungezogen-angezogen.ch/test)

**Note :** Try check out as guest.

Comment: does this also happen when you change the used theme to the default magento one? if it works there thats probably a bug in the templatemonster theme. If not, its a bug from the update or from the other changes the templatemonster theme did

Answer (score 1):

If you open the browser console while performing checkout, you will see that one ajax request, in this case `checkout/onepage/savePayment` throws a server error, which is

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in /var/www/web16/html/magento/test/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php on line 194
```

You should debug this error, and see what type the $toCurrency variable is, because it's not an object, but neither it is null.